# foo(int) is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, string, arguments, overloading

I am trying to invoke my method `m1(int)`, but am getting an error when I try to use a String as the input.

What is the reason behind it ?

```
class TestSuper
{

    public void m1(int i)
    {
        System.out.println("int-arg");
    }
    public void m1(float f)
    {
        System.out.println("float-arg");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestSuper t = new TestSuper();
        t.m1(10.5f);
        t.m1(10);
        t.m1("Name");  // <- Where I get the error.
    }

}
```

Comment: Because a `String` is not a `float` **or** an `int`.

Comment: But it takes char so...

Comment: A `String` is not a `char`; but a `char` is an integral type (and can be *widened* to an `int`).

Comment: like t.m1('A') by overloading concept

Comment: Create another overloaded method: 
 `public void m1(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("String-arg");
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you are trying to cast between an Object, `String`, and a primitive, `int`. This simply will not work. Objects cannot be cast to primitives, and vice-versa.

A `String`, comprises of an array of `char`'s wrapped into an Object.
An `int`, comprises of a single signed decimal number.

When you attempt to run a method which requires an `int` with a `String`, you are not supplying it with a number, you are supplying it with a `char`, which then has to be cast to an `int`.

Besides, the way you have setup overloading, there is no way to differentiate between weather or not you are using the `m1(int)` method or `m1(float)` method. To fix this, you should add the following method:

```
public void m1(String s) {
    System.out.println("String-arg");
}
```

For the future, to cast between a `String` and `int`, use:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("44");  // Equal to 44.
```

Which then runs the risk of giving back a `NumberFormatException`, so to be safe:

```
public void randomMethod(String input) {
    int i = 0;
    try {
        i = Integer.parseInt(input);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}  // Fill in with your requirements.
}
```